# Null Reference Excepetion when trying to assign value to two dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

Hi I have an assignment in which I need to resolve a system of linear equations using Gausian elimination method.

This is my code so far:

```
 private static double[][] equation = new double[][]
 {
  new double[] {0.0, 8.0, 2.0, -7.0},   
  new double[] {3.0, 5.0, 2.0, 8.0},
  new double[] {6.0, 2.0, 8.0, 26.0}    
 };

 private const int rowSize = 3;
 private const int columnSize = 4;
 private static int pivotRow;
 private static int curentRowIndex;

 public static void GetTriangularMatrix()
 public static void GetTriangularMatrix()
    {
        PrintMatrix();

        for (int k = 0; k <= columnSize - 2; k++)
        {
            curentRowIndex = k;
            double pivot = GetPivot(k);
            SwapCurentRowWithPivotRow(pivot);
            FindTriangularMatrix();
        }
    }

    public static double GetPivot(int curentPivot)
    {
        double pivot = equation[curentPivot][curentPivot];
        pivotRow = curentPivot;

        for (int i = curentPivot; i <= rowSize - 1; i++)
        {
            if (pivot < equation[i][curentPivot])
            {
                pivot = equation[i][curentPivot];
                pivotRow = i;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Pivot Row is " + (pivotRow + 1));
        Console.WriteLine("Pivot is " + pivot);

        return pivot;
    }

    private static void SwapCurentRowWithPivotRow(double pivot)
    { 
        if(pivot != equation[curentRowIndex][curentRowIndex])
        {
            double temp;
            for (int i = 0; i <= columnSize - 1; i++)
            {
                temp = equation[curentRowIndex][i];
                equation[curentRowIndex][i] = equation[pivotRow][i];
                equation[pivotRow][i] = temp;
            }
        }

        PrintMatrix();
    }

    public static void FindTriangularMatrix()
    {
        double[][] trangularMatrix = new double[rowSize][];

        for (int j = curentRowIndex + 1; j <= rowSize - 1; j++)
        {
            trangularMatrix[j][curentRowIndex] = equation[j][curentRowIndex] / equation[curentRowIndex][curentRowIndex];
        }
    }
```

At `FindTriangularMatrix()` method when I try to assign some value to the `triangularMatrix` I get back a null reference exception.

I believe this is more of a syntax problem , it may be something I am missing because I have never worked with two dimensional arrays before.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Comment: That is because you have not assigned an array to `trangularMatrix[i]` for any `i`. It will always be null. In the declaration, you need to do something like `double[][] trangularMatrix = new double[rowSize][someNumber];`

Comment: I have tryed writing something luke this before:  double[][] trangularMatrix = new double[rowSize][columnSize]; but visual studio throws this error on compile Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']' 1

Comment: I see C# has different syntax from Java (which i was going by) in this respect; [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4384236/1086871) should clear it up.

Comment: Have you considered using a rectangular array instead of a jagged array? `double[,] triangularMatrix = new double[rowSize, columnSize]`?

Comment: that was the problem I was not aware that there was a difference.After using a rectangular array everything worked perfectly

Comment: try to debug it and say where do you get this exception and what are the values, did you tru to debug it ?